# MinWidth don't working in MainPage.xaml (UWP)

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my UWP app, I make the MinWidth 800, but it can get smaller when I run it.
MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page ............
      ............
      MinWidth="800">

</Page>
```

I want to my app can't get smaller than 800 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to set the mini size of the UWP window. In general, we will use [ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize(Size) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize?view=winrt-22621) to set the mini size of the UWP app. But this is not suitable for your scenario. You are asking for a mini width as 800 and the **largest** allowed minimum size for this API is 500 x 500.

If you want to keep your app in a preferred size, what you could do is handle the [sizechanged event of the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.sizechanged?view=winrt-22621). When the app is resized and if the width of the app is less than 800, you could adjust the size of the window back to 800.

**Code example:**

```
     public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var newszie = args.Size;
        if (newszie.Width<800) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("smaller than 800");
            var targetsize = new Size(800, 600);
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(targetsize);
           
        }
    }
```